# RSpec undefined method `each' in call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, grape-api

In my Grape API I've got an endpoint which is responsible of receiving data from CMS webhook - it works well but below specs are failed:

```
describe ::Webhooks::Cms::ReceiveWebhook, type: :request do
  subject(:call) { post endpoint, params: params, headers: basic_authorized_headers(auth_params) }

  let(:endpoint) { 'webhooks/Cms' }
  let(:params) { { some: 'params' } }
  let(:auth_params) do
    {
      username: Rails.application.credentials.cms_user,
      password: Rails.application.credentials.cms_password,
    }
  end

  it 'returns a successful response' do
    call
    expect(response).to be_successful
  end
end
```

helper with `basic_authorized_headers` method from headers:

```
module AuthRequestHelpers
  def basic_authorized_headers(username: nil, password: nil)
    "#{username}:#{password}"
  end
end
```

I'm getting error:

```
 Failure/Error: subject(:call) { post endpoint, params: params, headers: basic_authorized_headers(auth_params) }

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `each' for "test@test.com:password":String
```

Here is my controller:

```
module Cms
  class ReceiveWebhook < Base
    desc 'Receive data of CRUD actions from CMS webhook'

    http_basic do |user, password|
      user == Rails.application.credentials.cms_user &&
        password == Rails.application.credentials.cms_password
    end

    post :cms do
      status 200
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post` expects a hash for the `headers` param, you're passing a string.

```rb
subject(:call) { post endpoint, params: params, headers: { 'Authorization' => basic_authorized_headers(auth_params) } }
```

Also, *usually* basic auth requires the "Basic" keyword, and that the [credentials be encoded in Base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617):

```rb
module AuthRequestHelpers
  def basic_authorized_headers(username: nil, password: nil)
    encoded_credentials = Base64.encode64("#{username}:#{password}")
    "Basic #{encoded_credentials}"
  end
end
```